# Is it possible to declare and define a bit field in Cython?

Tags: cython

In C/C++ you can declare a [bit field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) as a struct by specifying the number of bits to use for a given field in a struct. e.g.:

```
typedef struct {
    char threeBits : 3;
    char fiveBits : 5;
} MyBitField;
```

If we ask the size of this we get 1:

```
printf("sizeof(MyBitField): %d\n", sizeof(MyBitField)); // prints: "sizeof(MyBitField): 1"
```

Is it possible to define these special kind of structs in Cython?

I looked at the [docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#styles-of-struct-union-and-enum-declaration) and didn't see any syntax to support this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still hoping for a better answer, but in a pinch, you can always [cheat](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#including-verbatim-c-code)

```
cdef extern from *: 
    """ 
    struct MyBitField { 
        char threeBits : 3; 
        char fiveBits : 5; 
    }; 
    """ 
    cdef struct MyBitField: 
        char threeBits 
        char fiveBits 
        
cdef MyBitField mbf = MyBitField(2,3) 
print(mbf) 
print(sizeof(mbf))
```

which prints:

```
{'threeBits': 2, 'fiveBits': 3}
1
```

Comment: I don't think there is a better solution